# Android Studio - Firebase - Pesquisa e editar dados

Tags: android, firebase, app, crud

Estou criando um aplicativo usando o Android Studio, que armazena as informações dos clientes no Firebase : [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso criar uma forma de pesquisar esses clientes pelo nome ou CPF, caso seja necessário mudar alguma coisa, daí queria saber se alguém pode dar alguma dica ou sabe algum tutorial interessante para isso..

Answer (score 0):

Podes encontrar o registro desejado utilizando uma verificação sequencial com o comando **for**, conforme exemplo de código abaixo :

```
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mDatabase.child("clientes").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (Objects.equals(snap.child("cnpj").getValue(), "999.999.999-99")) {

                    // seu codigo aqui

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

O código acima irá ler sequencialmente do primeiro ao último registro e se houver o cnpj informado, poderás coletar os outros dados do cliente.

Comment: Desta forma você tem que sempre trazeres todos os clientes e fazer o filtro no client. Usando o Query do firebase pode filtrar os dados e diminuir o tempo e quantidade de dados trafegados.

Answer (score 0):

Você vai ter que usar uma query no Firebase, para poder filtrar. Tenta fazer desta forma:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("clientes");

Query clienteCnpj = ref.orderByChild("cnpj").equalTo("CNPJ");

clienteCnpj.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot clienteSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```